ApolloError: Variable "$image" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid
const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    setImage(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
   
    try {
      const response = await uploadImage({
        variables: {
          image: image,
          userId: user?.id,
        },
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

//backend code
 @Mutation(() => UserType)
  async uploadImage(
    @Args('image', { type: () => GraphQLUpload }) image: FileUpload,
    @Args('userId') userId: string,
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.getUserById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user is not exist ');
    }
    const imageLink = await this.cloudinaryService.uploadAudio(
image,
      'song-audio',
    );

    const newUser = await this.userService.updateUserImage(userId, imageLink);
    return newUser;
  }

i applied the same mutation in the altair graphql client and it upload the image perfectly but after that i tried in frontend (next js ) it gives me the same error every time that invalid image value.
i want to uplaod the image using the next js but some how it gives me the error invalid value of
$image
